# Should/can "native English speaker" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

Should/can "native English speaker" be hyphenated?

"Native English speaker" vs. "Native English-speaker"

Answer (score 1):

For clarity’s sake, I recommend neither.  Instead say *a native speaker of English* so that there can be no aural confusion, as hyphens are silent.

Answer (score 1):

It can, but it shouldn't. Hyphens seem to be the source of much confusion. Seeking to explain it to a colleague, I boiled it down to the following:

Use hyphenation to join together an adjective and a noun, in order to use that new construction as a standalone adjective.

E.g.,

> Two native English speakers were scheduled to meet with the native-English-speakers' board of trustees.

*Native-English speakers* implies that "native English" is a separate item from *English which is spoken natively.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eric. "It can" as in it would be correct, or that it is possible to type/write it, but that it would be a grammatical error?